# Which Mac Application Support Sub Folders Name convention I should use? (dont want to be rejected)

Tags: macos, mac-app-store, special-folders

I am  looking for where I should save my app stuff, and after a quick search I found this:
[Cocoa equivalent of .NET's Environment.SpecialFolder for saving preferences/settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359590/cocoa-equivalent-of-nets-environment-specialfolder-for-saving-preferences-sett)
and this:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH3-SW3

Then I look at my Application Support Folder and noticed that almost every app uses the AppName and not the BundleID as apple suggests in its documentation.

I want to make sure I choose the right one, because I heard that some apps got rejected for writing in a ~/Library/Application Support/ subdirectory with different name than the app's name.

- **IN SHORT:**

Which naming convention you think I should use?
Does it matter when they are reviewing apps? Both are OK?

Thank you

Comment: I cant comment on being rejected or not, but from a user perspective i expect to finde stuff like that in `~/Library/Application Support/Application Name` and it makes me kinda fussy if thats not where it is :-)

Comment: I agree with you, but I just want to reduce my rejection probability because I am about to send my app to them to review this week and I will not have time to change my app for sandboxing requirements that will be applying soon... I am planning the sandboxing refactoring just for the first update.

And my app is, sadly, one of those that, by its nature, will be severely affected by these new stupid rules. So, updating it to work with these restrictions will be a 2+ week work =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, answering my own question, just to not leave as is...

I just called NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES ); to get the application support folder and appended the App name.
I hardly believe something like that will be a reason for a rejection, as NSApplicationSupportDirectory appears to return te correct folder even when the app is sandboxed.

Comment: So, No rejection, here is my app http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/joystick-show/id515886877 =)